# Not locking tables but am getting error "General error: 1100 Table 'entities' was not locked with LOCK TABLES"

Tags: mysql, locking

I am trying to run a simple `INSERT` query, but am receiving an error stating:

```
General error: 1100 Table 'entities' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

I have not used an implicit `LOCK TABLES` before the query.

Doing a `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` just previous to the query yeilds:

```
Id      User    Host    db      Command Time    State   Info
646     my_user my-win-8:4018 db_name Query   0               SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

The query I am running is:

```
INSERT INTO entities (type, user_id, created, creator, updated, updater)
VALUE ('some-type', NULL, '2013-07-02 01:30:18', '3', '2014-08-28 23:45:44', '2');
```

Comment: `VALUE` should be `VALUES`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually either can be used. `{VALUES | VALUE}` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Comment: what information are you omitting?  You are trying to do this from command line mysql, a procedural language?  It looks like you're using windows.  One guess I have, is that if mysql is running locally, and you're using myisam, it could be a permissions issue where for some reason, the mysql server can't write to the data file for the table.

Comment: Only `VALUES` is permitted according to the SQL standard, didn't know MySQL ignored that.

Comment: @gview I am running this via a PHP script, on Windows. Running the same query in phpMyAdmin works fine.

Comment: Where is the code for the script then?